# Has anyone proposed Splitting Photography stack into to two; digital photography and analog photography?

Tags: discussion

Has anyone proposed Splitting Photography stack into to two different stacks; digital photography and Film photography ? Is it a good idea ? ( i say it is because my brain thought it up all by itself, I think )

Digital would be of coarse all things related to digital photography; equipment, techniques, post processing etc.

Analog would be of coarse all things related to film photography; equipment, techniques, film, developing, printing.

Opinions ?

Bueller, Bueller ?

Comment: Where would go discussions on lenses and filters, tripods and heads, lighting and studio equipment, and, above all,  general photography (composition, lighting, etc...).

Comment: Most of the time, Stack Exchange discourages proposing new sites that will fragment/split the current userbase. But for this meta discussion: what are the problems with the current site that you feel the need to split it?

Comment: Is there a purpose behind this Q, or was it just a transient thought you happened to have?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's a lot more in common between digital photography and analog photography than there is not in common. This is especially the case when things sometimes done using digital cameras when the end goal is not an image are not taken into account. This, using a camera primarily as a measuring device instead of with the primary goal to produce an artistic or documentary image for display is not considered "photography" here.

There's no need to split the site and then duplicate all of the content regarding things such as:

- Composition
- Lighting
- Metering
- Flash photography
- Lenses
- Shooting technique
- Selecting frames and displaying prints
- Tripods, camera straps, other accessories, etc.

Comment: Valid points for discussion for sure and I agree that all of the points mentioned do not need to be split onto another stack so it is the correct answer to the question as asked ***BUT***, perhaps i should have asked a different question.  **We are seeing more and more film and darkroom related questions and i am of the opinion that an all encompassing photography  stack does not best serve the film/darkroom users**. Perhaps the question is: **Should there be a film/darkroom stack?**

Comment: @AlaskaMan I think it is more beneficial to  try and attract those interested in film photography to this stack so that they can also benefit from and contribute to the topics that both types of camera have in common. It's not like there's a movement here to discourage film questions. I don't think the site is so "busy" that the film folks feel drowned out in the noise, either.

Answer (score 8):

You make a better argument for tags than for different sites.  Analog vs Digital photography doesn't change photography on the whole, it changes only a relatively small part.  The technical means of developing the image are the only real change.  All of the artistic portions(concept, not technique), the ideas behind the development of the image, the mechanics of the camera itself are all more or less identical or extremely similar between the two.

To use a different example, this would be a bit like suggesting that a Cars Q/A should be split in to Manual Transmission and Automatic Transmission sites.  Yes, there are some functional differences between them in some areas, but they are still both fundamentally cars and the vast majority of things in the field are relevant to both.

Answer (score -2):

If at all, making the divide between photography and image editing/publication would make far more sense.... and maybe giving up the photo/video split instead, given that there are very few contemporary dedicated still and video cameras and accessories left at the end of 2019. Dividing between "stuff done in the field with cameras, lights and lenses" and "stuff done indoors with full sized computers" seems to slowly make more sense...

And, just a personal opinion, I do not think questions about optics theory or machine vision camera-side equipment should be off topic - there seems to be value in some (especially surplus) machine vision gear for pictorial photography and videography, so keeping that world nearby might ultimately be beneficial.

Comment: Agreed. And a  lot of the *"stuff done indoors with full sized computers"* already happens in GraphicDesign, even if it"s considered a bit off-topic by some.

Comment: I'm definitely not interested in filmmaking (or making family home videos). Can you find some examples of questions on the video site which we would currently consider off topic but which would actually build a better photography community here? I'm afraid that it'd just lead to *more* questions about the technical capabilities and features of particular gear.